# How to disable shipping method based on item count and a certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I have been looking for a way to condtionally disable two shipping methods

- table rate
- distance rate

Based on the item count.

By item count I do not mean quantity, I mean how many different products are in the cart. IE 2 Lamps and 3 tables in the cart would be an item count of 2 and a combined quantity of 5.

I would also like to ensure this rule is in effect for a certain category only.

I tried:

```php
function hide_shipping_count_based( $rates, $package ) {

    // Set count variable
    $cart_count = 0;

    // Calculate cart's total
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $value) {
        $cart_count ++;
    }

    // only if the weight is over 150lbs find / remove specific carrier
    if( $cart_count > 2 ) {
        // loop through all of the available rates

        unset( $rates[ 'distance_rate' ] );
        unset( $rates[ 'table_rate' ] );

    }

    return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_count_based', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following, explanation with comments added in the code

Conditions that must be met in this code are:

- At least 3 line items in cart
- 1 or more products belong to the *'categorie-1'* category
- *'distance_rate' and/or 'table_rate'* become unset if the previous 2 conditions are met

---

```php
function hide_shipping_count_based( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Count line items
    $count =  count( $package['contents'] );

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Set term (category)
    $term = 'categorie-1';

    // Check count
    if( $count > 2 ) {

        // Loop through line items
        foreach( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
            // Get product id
            $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];

            // Check for category
            if ( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // Loop trough rates
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Targeting
            if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'distance_rate', 'table_rate' ) ) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_count_based', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: More compact: `if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'table_rate', 'distance_rate' ) ) ) unset($rates[$rate_key]);`